# use filter filter in angular dragdrop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters, angular-dragdrop

here is a plunkr to illustrate my issue.

https://plnkr.co/edit/SdRii7l7Wsf9rbuM6byc?p=preview

when applying a filter filter to my angular collection (filling in the search box) then dragging the result to one of the wells. the filter is not applied. I attempted using the filter examples provided in the dragdrop documentation but it does not appear to be working.

```
   <div class="well"
               ng-repeat = "org in orgs"
                data-drop="true"
                ng-model="org.list"

               jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, applyFilter: 'filterIt'}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

- `$scope.search` in the template should just be `search`
- `applyFilter` needs to be a string
- after reading the docs, it seems the `applyFilter` option needs to be set on the draggable area, but maybe not the droppable area (since they don't share the same ng-model)

Here is a modified Plunkr that seems to apply the search filter correctly when the item is dropped: https://plnkr.co/edit/LCfDpGwptqODMEsi30UW?p=preview.